# Non Latin Characters & ouch

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm getting to know Cake PHP, which has unearthed a general question about best practice in terms of PHP / MySQL character set stuff, which I'm hoping can be answered here.

My (practice) system contains a mysql table of movies. This list was sourced from an Excel sheet, which was exported as CSV, and imported via phpMyAdmin.

I noticed that titles with more "exotic" glyphs have issues rendering in the browser, eg The é in Amélie. Using Cake or plain PHP, it renders as a `?`, unless transformed via `htmlentities` into a `&eacute;`. Links with the special characters don't render at all.

If I use my Cake input form to enter an `<alt>0233`, this is rendered correctly in source, but as `&Atilde;&copy;` via `htmlentities`.

After a quick SO search, I decided maybe UTF-8 would fix stuff, hence I

- changed the PHP source, and CSV file encoding to UTF-8
- made sure the `<meta>` stuff was there (it was already via Cake's default layout).
- made sure my browsers thinks the doc is UTF-8 (they do)
- changed the collation on the MySQL DB to utf-8 general_ci (as an educated stab from avalable UTF-8 options)
- deleted and reimported my data

However, I'm still stuck. I note that phpMyAdmin manages to render the characters "correctly" in it's HTML source when browsing records.

I sense that document encoding's to blame, however, am wondering if someone can provide the best answer to:

- what's the best way to move my data from Excel to MySQL to preserve glyphs?
- what's the optimum settings for my tables to accommodate this?
- I'd prefer to use UTF-8 to natively display the likes of é, what can I do in Cake to avoid making loads of calls to the likes of htmlentities ie is there a configuration setting or way I set stuff up that makes this more friendly and lets Cake native helpers like `Html->link` work?

Some code, just in case:

movies controller excerpt..

```
function index() {
        $this->set('movies' , $this->Movie->find('all'));

}
```

index.ctp view excerpt

```
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($movie['Movie']['title']); ?>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($movie['Movie']['title'] , 
    array('controller' => 'movies' , 'action' => 'view' , $movie['Movie']['id'])); ?>
    </td>

    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link("Edit", 
    array('action' => 'edit' , $movie['Movie']['id'])); ?>
    </td>

    <td>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', array('action' => 'delete', $movie['Movie']['id']), null, 'Are you sure?')?>
    </td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help / tips.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the MySQL connection is set to UTF-8 while importing the data. The collation is only used for sorting and comparison, not for saving data.

You can set the charset of the connection using `SET NAMES 'utf-8';` in the beginning of your SQL file.

Comment: Thanks. MySQL character set & table are set to UTF-8. I only have DB access via PHP MyAdmin. File import setting is UTF-8. Import file is a one column list (ie not SQL). Character(s) display as correct glyph in phpMyAdmin client (ie browse recs & viewing html source). Anything else I can try, taking into account constraints?

Answer (score 1):

That question comes here often.

UTF8 should work. Make sure that:

1. Your database collation uses utf8 (utf8 bin general)
2. You html document encoding tag is set to utf8
3. AND VERY IMPORTANT - most people forget that bit - make sure all your source files are saved as utf8. Use notepad++ on pc or Coda/TextMate/TextWrangler on mac to make sure the encoding is correct. If you don't do that, some transformation/re-interpretation of the characters may happen

**EDIT**: And forget about htmlentities, you don't need it if you use utf8 encoding all throughout

Comment: Cheers. All stuff above appears to be in place (see original question).