# Validation messages and accented characters

Tags: validation, cakephp, non-ascii-characters

I've a little trouble with validation messages and accented Characters (like "è" , "à", "ò" and other). If the validation message in my model contains one of the accented characters, no message was displayed :-(

I tried to use "`&egrave;`" instead of "è" and the message was displayed BUT the "`&egrave;`" isn't converted in "è" , so the message looks like "Il nome &egrave obbligatiorio" (italian sentence that means "Name is required").

Have you idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: `&egrave;` Did you miss the semicolon at the end?

Comment: I use semicolon at the end. It was a typo in the question only.

Comment: Duplicate of thousand others like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948121/non-latin-characters-ouch/5948166#5948166 In Short: save your file properly (utf8) if you use utf8 characters in them.

Comment: @mark : In all my files (Controllers , Views and others) I use `&egrave;` and it works ! Only in models files i've the error.. However I'll check the save format of my models.

Comment: there is no need to use `&egrave;` if you save them as utf8. however, it is usually better to use i18n, english base strings and PO files here.

Comment: @mark po files are only relevant for multilingual sites, for one language (irrespective of the language) it's not usual (or I would say recommended) to use po files.

Comment: @NikoDev It's not really relevant that using html entities "works", if using utf-8 characters does not work it simply means a charset mismatch (which typically is caused by saving files as not-utf8 and serving html pages as utf8). Controllers and especially models shouldn't be using html entities at all.

Comment: @AD7six I disagree. Using and working with "different languages" all the time I highly recommend to do so even for a single language (in a non-english one, of course). It keeps those language specific utf8 chars out of the files and the code is cleaner if it is in english with a single source to translate. especially in controllers/models etc. it is also easier to work with in a team where one is not a native speaking person - or code reviewers. I am not saying that it is no overhead. But the overhead can be disregarded in favor of the obvious advantages IMO. Well, matter of preference.

Comment: @mark you are assuming/implying the op does too; it's quite common to work exclusively in one language, and using po files _adds work_ in that circumstance. `It keeps those non utf8 chars out of the files ` - you say that like it's part of the problem.